# javascript empty loop body

Tags: javascript

I'm working through [eloquent javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter2.html#p1ad637f9) and I don't understand this bit of code

```
for (var current = 20; current % 7 != 0; current++)
  ;
console.log(current);
```

It states that it checks for the first number greater than 20 that is divisible by 7 and `console.log()` would produce 21.

But I read that as start at 20, check if `current` divided by 7 has no remainder to see when we break the loop. But straight away 20 mod 7 == 6 meaning it does not equal 0 or (`20 % 7 != 0`).

So shouldn't the for loop break straight away and `console.log(current)` produce 20? What am I missing here?

Comment: Hi, 20 mod 7 == 6 not 4

Comment: You messed up the condition part of a `for` loop a bit. It have to be `true` in order to continue the loop, and `20 % 7 != 0` is obviously `true`. (`!=` checks for *inequality*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A loop continues as long as the condition is met.

```
20 % 7 != 0 // 6 != 0 is true, so condition is met and loop continues

21 % 7 != 0 // 0 != 0 is false, so condition fails and loop halts
```

---

> *"... check if `current` divided by 7 has no remainder"*

No, it's *"check if `current` divided by 7 does NOT have no remainder"*.

I think the negative condition is throwing you. Basically, you need to ask if the condition is a true statement.

So if I'm the condition, and you're the loop, and I say *"six does not equal zero"*, you would say *"that's true"*, so you would agree to let the loop continue.

But then if I say *"zero does not equal zero"*, you would say *"that's false"*, and would halt the loop.

---

A clearer condition would be *"check if `current` divided by 7 does have a remainder"*. No double negative, so it could be written as:

```
for (var current = 20; current % 7; current++) ;
```

or as:

```
for (var current = 20; current % 7 > 0; current++) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong here. Simply change the `;` line to this line, and you'll get the idea:

```
for (var current = 20; current % 7 != 0; current++) {
    console.log('current value is ' + current ' +
    ' and the mod result is ' + current % 7);
}
```